# How to access iPhone filesystems via USB (from Windows)

Tags: c++, c, ios, filesystems, usb

I wish to make an SMS analysis tool that downloads the SMS.db file from an iPhone device, connected via USB. I am coding in C++ and would like to know how applications such as DiskAid and iPhone Explorer access the entire filesystem via USB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The device is going to have to be jailbroken to access the SMS database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone Explorer requires iTunes; probably it works by employing the iTunes COM API (I know there is one). Anyway, it does not show the full filesystem; just the parts that iTunes exposes. And AFAIK, the SMB.db is not exposed.

Or maybe it taps into some lower-level API that iTunes itself consumes.

Not sure about DiskAid.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it will use either Manzana, or something similar to it.  It uses one of the iTunes libraries.